# How do I make hair particles appear on top of the emitter and not through it?

Tags: particles, hair

[image]

How to make grass appear on top of ground not in middle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things to verify when making grass or other hair objects from a mesh item:

1. Is object origin where you want the particle to attach to the ground?

[image]

2. Are you copying rotation? (You can, or can not, as Yoda would say... but be aware of what it is set for...)

[image]

3. Are you adding roundness or radius?

[image]

4. Is the object being used as a hair positioned weirdly relative to global axes?

[image]

5. Is there weirdness interjected by velocity or physics settings?

[image]

And I bet I am forgetting some... but the one I always start with is "where is my origin, and what is the object rotation?"

Comment: Plural of axis = axes... axes is the only word in English that can be the plural of three different singular noun forms--ax, axe, and axis.

Comment: Outstanding! An economy of words, for sure.