# My particles are halfway inside the floor, can I move them up the z axis?

Tags: mesh, particles

[image]

As you can see, those bullets are halfway in. Floor normal face is facing the right way. I fiddled with most of the settings, but haven't found a way to raise them on the floor.

Haalp?

Blend file:
[image]

Comment: Try moving the "Origin" to the bottom of your mesh.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57576/how-do-i-make-hair-particles-appear-on-top-of-the-emitter-and-not-through-it. Normals of the emitter are important but have nothing to do with what is shown on the screenshot

Comment: @Dontwalk  I was sure that origin point was gonna fix the problem  once you mentioned it, but surprisingly after I changed my origin to bottom mesh, bullets were still halfway in. Other settings weren't the issue either as I reset everything.

Comment: @Boyka You moved the "Origin(s)" of the bullet particles correct? Also, it would be helpful if you posted your .blend file using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @Dontwalk added

Comment: Try changing the Emitter from "Hair" to "Emitter". Then change the "End" frame from 200 to 1.

Comment: @Dontwalk Can't see particles on the ground.

Comment: It worked for me with your .blend file. Try playing the Timeline from frame one. (I'm trying to upload your modified .blend now).

Comment: ah indeed, was on 0 frame, my bad. But on frame 1 it's still halfway inside and with next frames it just jumps and emits down by gravity.

Comment: Change the Emitter Velocity to Zero and change the Physics to "No". [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4124" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4124/)

Comment: @Dontwalk Hmm, it's still inside the floor, even with Physics on "no". Same result with your uploaded file. Also I can't seem to find Emitter Velocity, only "Emitter Geometry" and "Emitter Object" under Velocity.

Comment: @Dontwalk Is it fine on your end? I have Blender 2.79, maybe it's some kind of a bug because I had to change frames from 1 to 0 and back to 1 to have bullets in their original positions. Otherwise they were floating in the air.

Comment: I have 2.79 also. I re-saved the file I modified. Here [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4125" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4125/) We'll need to take this into chat if you need more help but Im not sure how...

Comment: Naah bro, you helped me a lot already. It's some kind of a bug probably. Plus I don't haven enough reputation for chat :D

Comment: thanks for taking the time. Appreciate it. By the way, the file you sent me showed me them like this:https://i.imgur.com/pM5TSvP.jpg So it's still for some reason considering origin somewhere in the middle. Freaking bugs!

Comment: @Dontwalk If interested, the issue was was with rotation as mentioned in other comment. Change the x rotation and apply it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix your problem is (from the file you uploaded) rotate your bullet object on the x axis by -90 degrees in object mode, then apply the rotation on your bullet with ctrl-a.

The reason your bullets are like that is because blender thinks that (for some reason) the y axis is what should be facing up. Rotating the bullet as describes above sets the origin point of the bullet on the bottom relative to the y axis.